# How to adjust the width of a \hdashline inside a pmatrix?

Tags: matrices, arydshln

I'm using `\hdashline` from the `arydshln` package to draw a horizontal line inside a `pmatrix`:

[image]

How can I reduce the width of this line to prevent it from touching the outer parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an `array` environment and make use of the `@{}` intercolumn specifiers to put in some negative space.  Here is one piece of example code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left(  
    \mkern4mu\begin{array}{@{\mkern-4mu}c@{\mkern-4mu}}
      \begin{pmatrix}
        r_{11}&r_{12}&r_{13}\\
        r_{21}&r_{22}&r_{23}\\
        r_{31}&r_{32}&r_{33}\\
      \end{pmatrix}
      \begin{pmatrix}
        x\\y\\z
      \end{pmatrix}
      \\
      \hdashline 1
    \end{array}\mkern4mu
  \right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: You get the same result without all the `\mkern` commands and with `\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}` for the outer array.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Are there any disadvantages of using `array` instead of `pmatrix`? Mostly I read that `amsmath` is recommended for anything concerning mathematics...

Comment: @ph4nt0m: In this instance, Andrew inserted some horizontal padding between the matrix and the parentheses, so using `array` is necessary; it requires a distinct placement of the parentheses. `\pmatrix` inserts the parentheses automatically, removing an "hook" into the location between the two constructs.

Comment: @Werner I understand that it is necessary to use `array` instead of `pmatrix` here. But when/why should I use ´pmatrix´ at all then? Is the fact that `pmatrix` already includes the parantheses really the only difference or are there any further advantages of the amsmath environments?

Comment: @egreg I put in the kerns to get a larger spacing to the outer brackets from the dotted line.  What you give works too but is tighter.

Comment: @AndrewSwann You're just adding some space and backing up by the same amount (on the left, vice versa on the right).

Comment: @ph4nt0m `arydshln` is desinged to work with array and tabular environments with the specific intent of making dashed rules that extend to out to the edges, and with various ways to tweak this.  For mathematics `pmatrix` is the first choice, but (even with the `mathtools` enhancement) it does not have good facilities for dealing block matrices containing dividing lines.

Comment: @egreg The negative kerns make the array look narrower to the `\hdashline` command.  Try replacing `-4mu` with `-40mu` and  you will clearly see that you get a shorter line.